# JEditable using Select on MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datatables, jeditable, datatable.select

I'm currently want to display a list of data using DataTables. And I want to be able to edit the record inline.  I could execute those with no problem.  The problem is, when I try to use drop down list(select) on one of the field for JEditable, that's when everything stuck to no where.

I would like to fetch the data from one of my table in MSSQL and dump it on `data : "{ 'test' : 'test' }"` for example.  but I cant find a way to do that. My JS knowledge is not that good.

Is there any way I could execute this? With this question, I include my current codes:
this is my initialization for Datatables and JEditable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myItem').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'Items/AjaxDataProvider',
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
                                { "sName": "ID",
                                    "bSearchable": false,
                                    "bSortable": false,
                                    "bVisible": false
                                },
                    { "sName": "NAME" , "sWidth" : "20%" },
                    { "sName": "UOM", "sWidth": "7%" },
                    { "sName": "REMARKS", "sWidth" : "8%"},
                                { "sName": "BARCODE", "sWidth": "8%" },
                                { "sName": "WITH SERIAL", "sWidth": "10%" },
                                { "sName": "MODEL" }
             ]
    }).makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "/Items/UpdateData",
        sAddURL: "/Items/AddData",
        sDeleteURL: "/Items/DeleteData",
        aoColumns: [
        {  },
        {   
            type: "select",
            onBlur: "submit",
            data: "{ ???? : ???? }"          
        },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  },
        {  } ]
    });
});
```

I would like to insert into `data` area in makeEditable for second  which is for UOM from this result:

```
var selectData = from a in db.Table select new[] { Convert.ToString(m.ID), Convert.ToString(m.Name) };
```

Anyone could give me a hand on solving this one?

Thanks a lot in advanced o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally manage to get the value for my selection list from SQL.  The steps are written at my blog at [Negative Zero](http://gunbladeiv.blogspot.com)